# Android Studio: Google Sign-in button does not appear

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am following a tutorial on how to implement google authentication in my Android app.
I have reached the stage where I add the google predefined button in my activity_login.xml file like it's explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin):

```
  <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
```

However, nothing appears in the Preview, except for a ***line*** where the button is supposed to be:
[image]
Here's a screenshot from the Tutorial to explain how it is supposed to appear:
[image]

I have followed each step carefully as explained in the tutorial so I really do not see why this is not working.
Mainly, I have added these to app/build.gradle in the dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0' //Added for google authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0' //Added for google authentication
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0' //Added for google authentication
```

And I have added this to project/build.gradle in the dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2' // Added for authentication
```

Any idea why the button isn't appearing??

**EDIT 1** : As demanded here's the whole XML code:
*PS:* A normal button appears normally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.LoginActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/image_bg_login">

    </ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:text="Things End. \n But memories last forever. \n Share your memories \n With the world"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic">

        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u show the whole xml code?

Comment: @IamaStudent I have added it in the EDIT 1

Comment: why do you use the inside RelativeLayout Height to match parent? @AhmedGhrib

Comment: @AjayKS Does it make a difference?

Comment: Some times, try to make that wrap content. @AhmedGhrib

Comment: @AjayKS No, I tried it. It has nothing to do with the button;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]try this,
This is the result that I got for the code.
''

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg_login"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activity.LoginActivity">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:text="Things End. \n But memories last forever. \n Share your memories \n With the world"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Login"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result that I got for the code.

Comment: Okay, so I guess the problem is with the dependencies, not the code itself. Did my code work for you?

Comment: I had added the out put I got. @AhmedGhrib

Comment: It's working now :) Could you please explain how you find the solution